# Force all items in list in each row to have the same height (each item has dynamic height)

Tags: html, css, list, row

I have a list of items `<li>`, the number of items in the list is dynamic, and the content as well. The list has 4 items per row, define by `float:left`. The height of each item is dynamic , and as a result the item in the next row gets "stuck" just before the highest item on the above row. Its results in a visually ugly list, and rows not being populated.

How can I force all the items in each row to be the height of the highest row? or, how to force all the items in the list to be the height of the highest items in the list?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
The final solution is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    var currHeight = -1;
    var prodDescHeight = -1;
    var diffHeight = -1;
    // get the max height of the list items
    $('.my_li_class').each(function() {
        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
    // set max height to all items 
    $('.my_li_class').each(function() {
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some code you tried?

Comment: BTW, I am not familiar with JS and was wondering if that might be the only solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use display:inline-block instead floatting.
So when it comes to another 'row', it's in fact a whole new line where next list items will sit.

Comment: I tried to avoid `inline-block` because I have read that it is not comaptible across all browsers. But I tested with FF and Chrome and it does the trick. But it does not really fixes the problem in hand. All the items are inlined to the bottom of each row, but their height is still varying across each row. This presents a different issue, I have to have each item in each row to have the same height - because of the header elements in of those items.

Do you have any ideas? is that a javascript solution?

Comment: javascript would be the solution, looking for the tallest, it would apply then this height to all of them.(foreach, offsetHeight, style.height) | Below IE8, add display:inline;+zoom:1 a quick search will tell you the ways to do that simply.