# Make list items in each row match dynamic height

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

I currently have the code below which produces a resizable list, except the li elements do not match the height of their neighbor. It's similar to the question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011822/force-all-items-in-list-in-each-row-to-have-the-same-height-each-item-has-dynam) with the exception that the number of items per row should be dynamic.
How can I make each li in a row match that row's highest li while preserving the existing functionality?

List example used in images:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.</li> 
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </li>
      <li>Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.</li>
      <li>Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam elementum laoreet lacus.</li>
      <li>Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate, cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.</li> 
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </li>
      <li>Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.</li>
      <li>Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam elementum laoreet lacus.</li>
      <li>Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate, cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    overflow: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    resize: horizontal;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 80vw;
    padding: 0px;
}
li {
    background-color: grey;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

It produces the following output: [resized to show 4 li per row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4IAv.png)
[resized to show 3 li per row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se1vX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have a look at [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid). It works great for just the scenario you're describing and gives you a lot of control over how your rows and columns should behave.

#### Example/Demo

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

li {
  background: #efefef;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
        pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.
      </li>
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas.
      </li>
      <li>
        Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu
        nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.
      </li>
      <li>
        Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam
        elementum laoreet lacus.
      </li>
      <li>
        Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate,
        cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
        pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.
      </li>
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas.
      </li>
      <li>
        Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu
        nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.
      </li>
      <li>
        Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam
        elementum laoreet lacus.
      </li>
      <li>
        Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate,
        cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  `height: 100%;` to your `li` in CSS:

```css
ul {
    overflow: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    resize: horizontal;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 80vw;
    padding: 0px;
}
li {
    background-color: grey;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
   <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.</li> 
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </li>
      <li>Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.</li>
      <li>Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam elementum laoreet lacus.</li>
      <li>Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate, cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas pharetra nunc vitae massa elementum ultricies a non ipsum.</li> 
      <li>Nunc porttitor pretium ex, in molestie lacus molestie eget.</li>
      <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </li>
      <li>Fusce faucibus lacus eu tellus interdum aliquet. Donec euismod nisi eu nisi dictum, a tincidunt sapien dictum.</li>
      <li>Fusce aliquet tempus ex quis tincidunt. Donec at varius enim. Nullam elementum laoreet lacus.</li>
      <li>Aenean id volutpat ipsum. Maecenas vulputate odio nec lectus vulputate, cursus volutpat nulla vehicula.</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this sets all <li> to the same height across all rows. abgreg's answer with grids solves this issue.